# Why do the websites of stackoverflow never get inappropriate posts

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, posting

I have been an active member of most of the websites of Stack Overflow for the last couple of months now. In this time I have never seen an inappropriate post of any kind.

By inappropriate I mean a post that I can flag.

I have seen some websites where posts need to be approved by the admins etcetera, but this is not the method used here.

Is the SO community just so fast that they remove everything bad before other people can see it? Or are the people that post here just genuinely nice people?

Comment: They do, they just get deleted extremely fast.

Comment: Except on Meta. On Meta, inappropriate posts are our bread and butter. :)

Comment: @Pekka: i resemble that remark...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It helps that this community is:

- numerous
- anal retentive
- bored ;-p

In short, junk posts *do* arrive (I see plenty with my ♦ hat on), but are dealt with very efficiently by the community:

- enough downvotes will remove a post from the front page
- enough flags will cause a post to be automatically deleted
- the moderators tend to be fairly good at following up on things that get *any* flags (I've deleted a few users just this evening)
- and for things that cause repeated problems there are a number of more... *permanent* options

Comment: is the permanent option a b&hammer?

Comment: Marc - you have a rhombic hat? :)

Comment: Ah nice points. All I have to say is keep up the good work. Its nice that your question is published immediately, and you don't have to go trough a lot of spam when looking for a nice question to answer.

Answer (score 7):

> Is the SO community just so fast to
>   remove everything before other people
>   can see it

Yes.. But I have to say that in my year here I've seen quite a few "inappropriate" posts (that have however been downvoted, closed and some deleted through the "report as spam" feature within minutes or even seconds).

Answer (score 4):

Yep, the community is fast and we have people in different timezones so there's good coverage. Most people are decent. I've seen more spammy nonsensical posts than outright inappropriate NSFW type of posts. Once these get closed they quickly drop off the main page so that's probably why they aren't as obvious. And if a mod is around it'll get deleted pretty quick.

Comment: And it REALLY helps that we users can do things like downvote and close questions without needing a moderator to intervene

Comment: @Jared good point. The points by @Kop and @Phoshi help too. 10K users can look at the list and add their votes to close/delete so things disappear faster. After a number of flag votes a post automatically gets removed too.

Comment: Yes this is a really good system, it is really nice posting here and not having to wait for approval.

Answer (score 3):

Once you hit 10k you'll get access to the flagged posts viewer. There's still quite a few, just the community is speedy.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that an average of 10 posts at any given time is "quite a few".

Comment: @mmyers: quite a few as in, more then none :P

Comment: New posts by new users also is a quick weed spot.